# ANR after app process was killed

Tags: android

After my application process was  killed and activities stack was restored I get ANR, but in log I can see that my Activity starting takes 1.5s?
What ca cause the such behavior? How to resolve this problem?

Comment: It depends entirely of your implementation, maybe you got a loading which take a long time

Comment: no, I don't have the such behavior. I get this error only after restarting activities stack.

Comment: Post the relevant parts of the logs and source code.